# Not working code insert multiple $_POST data from localhost xamp windows

Tags: php, html, mysql, post

I want to ask, why when I make php code `dilocalhost` XAMP windows he did not work? when I run it on linux vps her way? My code is nothing wrong in the way in XAMP windows?
I want to store a lot of data input from `$_POST` method.

This code not working fine in xamp windows but code work for linux debian vps :

```
<?php
include("session.php");
include("config.php");

$store = $_POST["store"];
$nik = $_POST['nik'];
$rak = $_POST['rak'];
$plu = $_POST['plu'];
$bar = $_POST['bar'];
$name = $_POST['name'];
$rh = $_POST['rh'];
$exp_date = $_POST['date_exp'];
$ip = $_POST['ip'];
$browser = $_POST['browser'];
$os = $_POST['sistem'];


foreach( $plu as $i => $p ) {

 $rhq = $rh[$i] * 86400;
 //$date = str_replace('/', '-', $exp_date);
 //$date_expq = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($date));
 $date_expq = strtotime($exp_date[$i]);

  $sql = "INSERT INTO data_exp (STORE, NIK, RAK, PLU, BAR, NAME, RH, DATE_EXP, IP, BROWSER, OS) VALUES ('$store', '$nik', '$rak[$i]', '$p', '$bar[$i]', '$name[$i]', '$rhq', '$date_expq', '$ip', '$browser', '$os')";

    if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
        header('Location: tambah.php?pesan=sukses');
    } else {
        echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error;
    }

}

$conn->close();

?>
```

Comment: May be datatype issue in sql. Provide detail error here.

Comment: this given : Undefined index: store,Undefined index: nik, Undefined index: rak and etc

Comment: do `$nik = isset($_POST['nik']) ? $_POST['nik'] : null; ` and change other post variables in the same way and see what happens

Comment: tomorrow I will try, in my linux vps work, :) it's night here, I want to rest